# Page break doesn't work in chrome for Google graph

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, graphics

I am trying to set the page break with [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart), but the page break is not working.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 chartPrint" funds-chart data-item="vm.report.data"><!--google chart here--></div>  
    <div class="col-sm-12 chartPrint" total-chart data-item="vm.report.data"><!--google chart here--></div>               
    <div class="col-sm-12 chartPrint" allocation-chart data-item="vm.report.data"><!--google chart here--></div>              
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chartPrint {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-after: always;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -webkit-column-break-after: always;
}
```

I have done some research and -webkit-column-break should have worked, but it didn't. Did anyone solve this issue with Google graph? Is there a Firefox page-break syntax? Any help would be appreciated